# Como funciona os tipos de dados apos constante no C?

Tags: c

Estou lendo alguns códigos e me deparei com o seguinte código

```
#define foo unsigned int
#define i typedef
```

eu sei como funciona esse unsigned e signed, typedef etc, mas eu não estou conseguindo entender como isso funciona na constante.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Este exemplo mostrado na pergunta não serve para nada de útil, a não ser demonstrar a diretiva `#define`.

O resultado disso é o seguinte:

```
#define foo unsigned int
#define i typedef

// bla bla bla

foo x;     // literalmente: "unsigned int x;"
i int y;   // literalmente: "typedef int y;"
y z;       // literalmente: "int z;"
```

Como disse acima, **este exemplo** não serve para nada de útil, apenas para demonstrar a diretiva `#define`. Obviamente, a diretiva `#define` é muito útil e aparece bastante nas próprias bibliotecas da linguagem C.

Comment: nossa cara é isso mesmo =D obg. mas seu exemplo serve para coisas útil sim, um ex e que a libc usa ele dessa forma que vc mostrou :)